# dropdown not working AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

> I have a problem when I list the dropDown. I look with the Chrome inspect It looks like the data is there but for some reason, when I click it, the drop down is not displayed.
>   I bring data from the BooksController and it load the all options ok, but is not displaying the list, it might be something on html but I can't realize what.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('BooksController', function($scope, LocationService) {
        $scope.categories = [
        {
            "Id": "-1",
            "Name": "All Books"
        }, {
            "Id": "0",
            "Name": "Computer Science"
        },{ 
            "Id": "1",
            "Name": "Physics"
        },{ 
            "Id": "2",
            "Name": "History"
        },{ 
            "Id": "3",
            "Name": "Geography"
        }, {
            "Id": "4",
            "Name": "Fiction"
        }];
        $scope.categoryId = null;
        $scope.BooksList = null;

        LocationService.GetBooks().then(function(d) {
            $scope.BooksList = d.data;
        });
        $scope.GetBookByCategory = function() {
            $scope.BooksList = null;
            LocationService.GetBooksFiltered($scope.categoryId).then(function(d) {
                $scope.BooksList = d.data;
            }, function(error) {
                alert('Error!');
            });
        }
    })
.factory('LocationService', function ($http) {
        var fac = {};
fac.GetBooksFiltered = function(categoryId){
    return $http.get('/Home/Get?predicate=' + categoryId)
}

fac.GetBooks = function(){
    return $http.get('/Home/GetAll')
}

        return fac;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-right">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Filter By: {{item.Name}}
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li data-ng-repeat="item in categories" dataitem-id="{{item.Id}}"><a     href="#">{{item.Name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**strong text**

Comment: did you add ng-controller="BooksController" in your html code?

Comment: or defined it in an app.js?

Comment: must be define in html also. show your full html code

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your BooksController to your HTML Code, like someone said in a comment.

Just add this inside the `.pull-right div` tag:

```
ng-controller="BooksController"
```

Also, you should have an `ng-app="MyApp"` attribute on another html tag that's a parent of the `.pull-right` div tag in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont use ng-app and ng-controller in your html code 
see here is working now.

```
 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
{{test}}
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in categories" dataitem-id="{{item.Id}}"><a     href="#">{{item.Name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vs8GA8DrQlKzo36PVDQ5?p=preview)